# doxygen inline sources only for one file or one function

Tags: inline, doxygen

is it possible to include the source only for a file or even only for some functions?
INLINE_SOURCES enables/disables it only for all files.
Maybe there is a command for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample is what you are looking for.